# Removing performance overhead

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, database

I've narrowed down a performance overhead within my application to this block:

```
Server currentServer = new Server(databaseConnection.DataSource);
Database currentDatabase = currentServer.Databases[databaseConnection.InitialCatalog];

foreach (View view in currentDatabase.Views)
{
    if (view.IsSystemObject == false)
    {
        if (view.Name.Equals(viewName))
        {
            MessageBox.Show(parent, "A virtual table with that name already exists! Virtual\ntable not created.", "Not created", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Information);
            break;
         }
         else
         {
             valid = true;
             break;
         }
    }
}
```

I would basically like to iterate over database views which do not belong to the system. However, with this approach, the `SMO` library iterates through all views regardless. Any idea how it can be arranged?

**EDIT:**

For example I've only got around 10 user-defined views, but over 1000 system ones. How can I skip the system views and iterate through the user-defined ones only?

Comment: This is not a big performance bottleneck.  What are you doing with the views... that is the slow part.

Comment: @Hogan - I've added the complete code. The system spends way too long on this.

Comment: Ah.  Now I see.  Also show the definition of currentDatabase.Views -- I'm guessing that is where the time is spent making the query to the server

Comment: @Hogan `Views` here is presumably SMO's [Database.Views Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.database.views.aspx), which populates a collection of all views in the DB (without prejudice between user-views and system-views).

Comment: That's right @MarcGravell. Going to try your suggested appraoch infact.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not clear what API you are using - but if you drop down to regular TSQL / ADO.NET, you can look at things like `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` / `sys.views`, which only contain the user-defined views. The system views are in `sys.system_views` (both are in `sys.all_views`). This will do all the restriction ***at the server***, so if you query `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS` / `sys.views`, the only data coming back over the wire is the data you are interested in. If you filter at the *client* you need to pay to transport all the data you *aren't* interested in too.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. So you'd suggest that I forget the SMO library for this task?

Comment: @DotNET if someone comes back with a good way to do it with SMO, then fine. I'm just saying that alternatives exist if no good SMO option is forthcoming.

Comment: @DotNET with the edited code, you need to transfer *even less* data - just an `EXISTS` test, so one row coming back. Heck, you might even just be able to use `OBJECT_ID(@name)` and checking for null / not-null

Comment: Yes, if he is just looking to see if a view of a name exists a query of the IMFORMATION_SCHEMA views is the way to go.  Never used SMO so who knows via that.

Comment: Thanks all, I'll look into this approach. However there are further operations that will be carried out later on too, i.e. getting the names of all these views. Can this method help in that aspect too?

Comment: @DotNET yes, that API includes names etc; try `select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS`, for example